# How can I select unique and duplicated rows exlude with different values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions, having

How can I fetch this table as expected in Oracle. I'm try to do this like below select but its not give me the right result. What I expect is fetch only the unique ones and exclude if these is a record like different values. Sorry for if asked before but I couldn't find it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ...
WHERE number IN ( SELECT name
                  FROM (SELECT *
                        FROM table
                        WHERE number IN ('Mel','Jose','Kim')
                  ) ds
                  GROUP BY number
                  HAVING COUNT (*) = 1)
```

Current result:

```
 number name
   aaa   Mel
   asd   Jose
   fsa   Jose
   xdf   Jose
   zzz   Kim
   zzz   Kim
```

Expected result:

```
aaa Mel
zzz Kim
```

Comment: Why your expected O/P has 101/Kim Row?

Comment: Because it's dublicated but unique on group by not like 212,313 Jose

Comment: Then 112, 212, 313 all makes Jose unique on group by..

Comment: may be i should ad my question count on the third column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close - I think you were just missing the distinct in the count in your having clause.

E.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 100 nmbr, 'Mel' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 112 nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 212 nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 313 nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 101 nmbr, 'Kim' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 101 nmbr, 'Kim' NAME FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking data in your table
-- you already have this table, so you would just need the below sql:
SELECT min(nmbr) nmbr,
       NAME
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nmbr) = 1;

      NMBR NAME
---------- ----
       101 Kim
       100 Mel
```

---

Just to prove that it doesn't matter whether the nmbr column is of NUMBER or VARCHAR2 datatype:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 'aaa' nmbr, 'Mel' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'asd' nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'fsa' nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'xfd' nmbr, 'Jose' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'zzz' nmbr, 'Kim' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 'zzz' nmbr, 'Kim' NAME FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking data in your table
-- you already have this table, so you would just need the below sql:
SELECT min(nmbr) nmbr,
       NAME
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT nmbr) = 1;

NMBR NAME
---- ----
zzz  Kim
aaa  Mel
```

Comment: sorry, i guess i miss directed you can you look again i change the numbers as letters

Comment: it doesn't matter whether they are numbers or letters - you're after rows where there is either a single row for the name, or exactly one unique value across all rows for the number/letter identifier, right? That's what the `having count(distinct nmbr) = 1` gives you. By that reasoning, `MIN(nmbr)` (or even `MAX(nmbr)`) is going to return the only value it can do, since there's only a single value available to work over. E.g. in the case of Mel, there's only one number (be it 100 or aaa), so the min(nmbr) = max(nmbr) = nmbr. In the case of Kim, there are two rows with the same number, so ...

Comment: ... the same reasoning applies. We only use the min/max aggregate function here to collapse the rows to a single row per name, otherwise you'd get two rows output for Kim, which you indicated you didn't want in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by `nested sql` with `the inner part` eliminate repeating ones with respect to `id` & `name`, and in `the outer part` eliminate repeating ones with only `name` like in the following statement :

```
SELECT MAX(id),name 
FROM (SELECT id,name FROM mytable GROUP BY id, name)  
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
ORDER BY MAX(id);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ID       NAME
-----    ------
100      Mel
101      Kim
```

[D e m o 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3461a/1)

> *exactly the same sql works for your second case :*
>
> [D e m o 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2646/1)

Comment: my be i should change the number because i cant get max, sorry, i guess i miss directed you can you look again i change the numbers as letters

Comment: @debegris i've edited for the case of both columns  to be string.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Boneist i appreciate your effort.